# Anonymously Add Bug to TFS (without authenticating)

Tags: tfs

We have a set of internal testers on our corporate network that are not on the domain (and getting them there is not a possibility for me as a dev). The use case is that a walk up kiosk type device is under test.

I'd like them to be able to submit bugs to a TFS repository without them having to authenticate at all, including entering their username.

**Constraints** (not questions)

- We have a preexisting screenshot thickclient app with the TFS API that will fill in all applicable fields (type type 'what went wrong').
- Obviously I don't want to embed a hardcoded username/password in this app.
- I understand that this is allowed without a TFS CAL via the Stakeholder role; all the users and devices qualify.
- I understand it's possible to wrap the TFS API with a web page and log errors as the web app's login. I'd like to avoid this as the point of not creating logins and registering testers and having them log on is to avoid the administrative costs and time extensions associated with that.

My biggest problem, I guess, is that the testing effort is pretty low budget!

#### Question: How to I Anonymously add a bug to TFS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't support to create/add bugs in TFS without any authentication. No matter how you connect to TFS, from web access page, Visual Studio or using TFS API, it all needs authentication. To do some actions in TFS, it also need to give these accounts permissions. https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/admin/setup-ad-groups

In your scenario, those testers are in other domain, you could make the 2 domains trust each other and add their account to TFS. Or if you can't want to do so, you could [create some local accounts](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770642.aspx) on your TFS server for those testers. And add these accounts to TFS.